# Converting date (with milliseconds) into timestamp

Tags: php, date, timestamp, strtotime, milliseconds

I have date format like `'25 May 2016 10:45:53:567'.`

I want to convert into the time stamp.

`strtotime` function returns empty.

```
$date = '25 May 2016 10:45:53:567';
echo strtotime($date); 
// returns empty
```

When I removed the milliseconds, it's working.

```
$date = '25 May 2016 10:45:53';
echo strtotime($date);
// returns 1464153353
```

Please sort out my issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: timestamp  - alco  called unixtime  it's seconds passed  from 1st january 1970 .  Seconds !!  Not miliseconds.  

You can't  do  that  using  strtotime .

Comment: Timestamps are seconds passed from 1 january 1970. They are stored in integers. You cannot store (or convert) milliseconds in timestamps. But you can convert them into two variables.

Comment: I got your points @MichałG & Prokthor. I am going to split out my field in to two. One for date with time and another one for milliseconds.

Comment: @John Conde Nobody discuss or ask about milliseconds in date timestamp or microtime in that question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2167916/convert-one-date-format-into-another-in-php). Then how this question become a duplicate ?

Comment: @tamilvanan: It is mentioned in the answer posted by John Conde.

Comment: @NisseEngström : In that answer, Milliseconds are trimmed from the given date time stamp. That's not my exact answer. But it's a good reference

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Split string:

```
$date = '25 May 2016 10:45:53:001';
preg_match('/^(.+):(\d+)$/i', $date, $matches);
echo 'timestamp: ' . strtotime($matches[1]) . PHP_EOL;
echo 'milliseconds: ' . $matches[2] . PHP_EOL;
// timestamp: 1464162353 
// milliseconds: 001
```

Comment: I am gonna to use your method. I am curious about your regular expression. Can you please tell that, how it works ?

Comment: ^ - beginning of string, (.+) - capturing group of all symbols, : - symbol ':',  (\d+) - capturing group of digits $ - end of string. Pretty simple. I would recommend use site https://regex101.com/ - you can make regexp and test it with ease there.

Answer (score 7):

Use `DateTime`:

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d M Y H:i:s:u', '25 May 2016 10:45:53:000');
echo $date->getTimestamp();
// 1464165953

// With microseconds
echo $date->getTimestamp().'.'.$date->format('u');
// 1464165953.000000
```

Comment: Thanks. I got same output for with and without milliseconds. What is the reason ?

Comment: With milliseconds
$date1 = DateTime::createFromFormat('d M Y H:i:s:u', '25 May 2016 10:45:53:567');
echo $date1->getTimestamp(); // 1464153353
Without milliseconds         $date2 = DateTime::createFromFormat('d M Y H:i:s', '25 May 2016 10:45:53');
echo $date2->getTimestamp(); // 1464153353 (In my localtime)

Comment: I've updated answer. Generally timestamp is Integer value.

Answer (score 2):

Use Datetime instead of date and strtotime.

```
//using date and strtotime
$date = '25 May 2016 10:45:53:000';
echo "Using date and strtotime: ".date("Y-m-d H:i:s.u", strtotime($date)); 

echo "\n";\

//using DateTime
$date = new DateTime();
$date->createFromFormat('d M Y H:i:s.u', '25 May 2016 10:45:53:000');
echo "Using DateTime: ".$date->format("Y-m-d H:i:s.u"); 
// since you want timestamp
echo $date->getTimestamp();
// Output
// Using date and strtotime: 1969-12-31 16:00:00.000000
// Using DateTime: 2016-05-28 03:25:22.000000
```

[Example](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/83d6269246de2afe54c38b2f601c46a4fb2d172e)